# Typescript object rest typings in argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm a bit new to Typescript, and I can do typings for 90% of my codebase. But when it comes to rest/spread operators, I am absolutely at a loss. I happened upon this today in our code (I did not write this) but I did figure out that it doesn't work:

```
interface searchClient {
  searchForValues({
    name,
    query,
    ...qp,
  }: {
    name: string;
    query: string;
    qp: QpInterface;  //???this part doesn't work
  }): Promise<any>;
 }

interface QpInterface {
  page?: number;
  hits?: number;
  attributes?: string;
}
```

It doesn't work because `qp` is designating the name of the key in the typing whereas what I want to type is the `...qp` part. Every key/value pair in `...qp` is typed by the QpInterface.

Here's a sample function call:

```
this.searchClient.searchForValues({
  name: 'title',
  query: 'little sheep',
  page: 5,
  hits: 2
});
```

I couldn't find much on this on the documentation. I've tried putting `...qp: QpInterface;` and `...QpInterface;` which didn't work. What is the best way to type `...qp` in the argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Until spread types are implemented in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727), you can use [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-type) for this:

```
interface searchClient {
  searchForValues({
    name,
    query,
    ...qp,
  }: {
    name: string;
    query: string;
  } 
    & QpInterface): Promise<any>;
 }
```